# Removing the script extension with URL rewriting on Apache

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

Given a (slightly theoretical) physical disk layout of:

```
\products\cameras\50d.jpg
\products\cameras\20d.jpg
\products\lenses\18-55.jpg
\products\lenses\28-135.jpg
\products.php
```

At the moment, I've URLs of the form:

```
/products.php/
/products.php/cameras/
/products.php/cameras/50d
```

With the products.php using the PATH_INFO to make a decision on what to display.

I'm struggling to rewrite the URL to remove the .php, but still allow static resources to be retrievable though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this works, and still allows resources within to work.

```
RewriteRule ^products([^\.]+)$ products.php$1
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly all those back-slashes must be forward-slashes. The `\` is used to "escape" special characters, not for folder separation.

Rewriting `products.php` to `products` will not work if you have a products folder already. I'd suggest moving all the images to a different directory like `/images/cameras/50d.jpg`. Then you can do this:

```
RewriteRule ^products products.php
```

With that you will need to parse the requested URL in PHP to find the variables. You could also use this:

```
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+) products.php?cat=$1
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/([^/]+) products.php?cat=$1&prod=$2
```

Now in your PHP script you automatically have the required variables via `$_GET['cat']` and `$_GET['prod']`.

EDIT: actually you're right, it *is* possible to have both, as long as all the images are limited to specific extensions. I think this will work:

```
RewriteRule ^products/(.+).jpg products/$1.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+) products.php?cat=$1
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/([^/]+) products.php?cat=$1&prod=$2
```

Comment: Would it not be possible to have a rule that kept the static resources where they are? (in reality, this is to replace some a poor man's approach, where there used to be a page per product/category which all called down to a shared library).

Comment: @Rowland Shaw: You can keep the `/products` directory, but that means you won't be able to use `/products` to display a page. There will always need to be a category and product parameter in the URL, e.g. `/products/lenses/18-55`, otherwise Apache will serve up the folder rather than the script by default.

Comment: @Rowland: added a possible solution